# Flutter Firestore query to return list

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using flutter and firebase to build a social network like program and currently need to find away to return a list of users that a user has not followed.

In order to accomplish that, I'm trying to generate a list of userIDs for which the user is following and then cycle through every userID (will likely put in a limit)and determine if that ID is in the list of userIDs that the user has not followed. I would then return a list of widgets for this.

Currently, I am trying to call a Stream of current followers in order to return a list of everyone the user is currently following, but Flutter is not letting me return a List from this?

```
class AddFollowers extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userId = 'userID imported here';

  Stream<List<String>> getFollowers(userId) async {
    final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('relationships')
        .document(userId)
        .collection('followers')
        .where("follower", isEqualTo: true)
        .getDocuments();
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
    return documents;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
        title: new Text("Find Your Following"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new StreamBuilder(
            stream: getFollowers(userId),
            builder:
                null //after returning the followers, I will build widgets of non-followers
            ),
      ),
//        new FindFollowerWidget(),
    );
  }
}
```

Any advice how to return this or better structure this is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: .getDocuments(); return Future<QuerySnapshot> not Stream. You Should Simply do - Firestore.instance
        .collection('relationships')
        .document(userId)
        .collection('followers')
        .where("follower", isEqualTo: true)
        .snapshots();
return result;

Comment: Thank you! That worked and was my issue! If you leave as answer, happy to accept it!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a `Stream`, I assume that you'd like to listen for realtime changes on your collections and documents. [FlutterFire](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) provides [`CollectionReference`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference-class.html) and [`DocumentReference`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html) that both have `snapshots()` method which returns a Stream that you can use.

For your use case, you could use it look like this:

```dart
// either set the collection as a Stream
Stream getCollectionStream(String userId){
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('relationships')
        .document(userId)
        .collection('followers')
        .where("follower", isEqualTo: true)
        .snapshots();
}

// or set it as a CollectionReference
CollectionReference getCollectionReference(String userId){
  // this returns a CollectionReference  
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('relationships')
        .document(userId)
        .collection('followers')
        .where("follower", isEqualTo: true);
}
```

and on your `Widget build()`

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    ...
    body: new Container(
      child: new StreamBuilder(
        // either this Stream snapshot
        stream: getCollectionStream(userId),
        // or use the reference with snapshots() method for the Stream
        // stream: getCollectionReference(userId).snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Something went wrong');
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            // display progressBar
            return Text("Loading");
          }
        ),
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

More details about listening to realtime changes on Cloud Firestore can be read in this [guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes).